# Httparty request query not parsed properly

Tags: ruby, httparty

I would like to pass some query parameters to `HTTParty.get`. I have a helper method to handle requests

```
def handle_request
  begin
    response = yield
    if response['Success']
      response['Payload']
    else
      raise Bondora::Error::ApiError, "#{response['Errors'][0]['Code']}: #{response['Errors'][0]['Message']}"
    end
  rescue Net::OpenTimeout, Net::ReadTimeout
    {}
  end
end
```

And another method to to make the request:

```
def investments(*params)
  handle_request do
    url = '/account/investments'
    self.class.get(url, :query => params)
  end
end
```

When I call this method like `investments({"User" => "test"})` I should end up with a GET request to `/account/investments?User=test`.
Unfortunately the request params are not parsed properly and the resulting request looks like this: `/account/balance?[{%22User%22=%3E%22test%22}]`

Any clue why this happens? I think it has something to do with the methods I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the method as `def investments(*params)`, `params` will contain an *array* of arguments, and want to pass a *hash* to your `get` call. So, either drop the asterisk and simply say `def investments(params)`, or use `query: params.first` later in the method.